# ff package dim error (selection)

Tags: r, bigdata

i search a solution to work with big data. So i tried "ff package". In my normal script i used following code for a selection in a 66896 x 362 data.frame:

```
setwd(wd)
bf <- read.table("G_BANKFULL_km3month.csv",header=T, sep=",",dec=".")


## read river discharge global, monthly vlaues 1971-2000##
memory.limit(size=16000)   # increase RAM
dis <- read.table('RIVER_AVAIL_7100_WG22.txt', header=T, sep="\t", dec=".")
##


## return only grid cells where bankfull is exceeded at least once during the time 
## period
test <- cbind(dis,bf$VALUE)
test2 <- test[(test[,-c(1:3)] > test[,length(test)]), ]
```

It works, if i use enough RAM. 
But i dont have always enough RAM for such a operation so i tried the "ff package".

```
library(ff)
## read Bankfull flow##
setwd(wd)
bf <- read.csv.ffdf(file="G_BANKFULL_km3month.csv",header=TRUE)
## read river discharge global, monthly vlaues 1971-2000##
memory.limit(size=16000)   # increase working memory
dis <- read.table.ffdf(file='RIVER_AVAIL_7100_WG22.txt', header=T, sep="\t", dec=".")
##read bankfull values as ff object##
bfvalues <- ff(bf[,2])
##combination of bf and dis ( see test <- cbind(dis,bf$VALUE))
dis_bf <- do.call('ffdf', c(physical(dis), list(bfvalues=bfvalues)))

dis_bf_test <-  dis_bf[(dis_bf[,-c(1:3)] > dis_bf[,length(dis_bf)]),]
```

The ffdf and the normal data.frame have the same structure etc. but if i try to this last selection it doesn't work and i get following error:

```
Error in as.hi.matrix(i, maxindex = nvw$n, vw = nvw$vw, pack = FALSE,  : 
argument "dim" is missing, with no default
```

Perhaps someone of you have worked with ff package and has an idea why it doesn't work. I am also happy about some ideas or information to other packages and solutions for working with big data.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you replace your code

```
dis_bf_test <-  dis_bf[(dis_bf[,-c(1:3)] > dis_bf[,length(dis_bf)]),]
```

with

```
require(ffbase)
open(dis_bf_test)
dis_bf_test <- subset(dis_bf_test, yourcolumnname > youothercolumnname)
```

where yourcolumnname represents the column you indicated by `dis_bf[,-c(1:3)]` and yourothercolumnname with the column you indicated with `dis_bf[,length(dis_bf)]`